# crash using malloc in a function called by another function in C [VS2010]

Tags: c, malloc

I want to cast malloc in a function , and i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxLength 4
typedef short int *set;


    void func(set *a)
    { 
      func1(a);
    }

    void func1(set *a)
    {
        *a=malloc(maxLength*sizeof(set));
        (*a)[0]=10;
        (*a)[1]=13;
        (*a)[2]=15;
    }

    void main()
    {
        set a;
        func(&a);
        printf("%d %d %d",a[0],a[1],a[2]);

    }
```

VS2010 CODE:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "12.h"
#define maxLength 4
typedef int *set;


void func(set *a){
    func(a);
}

void func1(set *a){
        *a=reinterpret_cast<set>(malloc(maxLength*sizeof(set)));
               (*a)[0]=10;
               (*a)[1]=13;
               (*a)[2]=15;
}
```

is this the way to do it in VS2010 ? because it compiled but crashed 
CRASH DETAILS : `Unhandled exception at 0x00c610a9 in 11.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.`
because in CODE BLOCKS it worked perfect

THE QUESTION IS: WHY IT DOES WORK IN CODE BLOCKS , BUT IN VS2010 DOES NOT

Comment: VS2010 has nothing to do with this. Your question should be simply "is this the way to do this, because (a) it doesn't seem to work, (b) it seems to work but crashes, (c) it seems to work but looks odd, etc...?

Comment: After fixing your code (You have no prototype so the `func1` call in `func`is assumed to be to `int func1()`) and fixing the return type for `main()`, this "works" under VS when compiled as C (*not* C++). So whats is the problem?

Comment: @WhozCraig dont worry , the prototypes are in the header file , but how do i compile in C in VS2010

Answer (score 3):

In your VS code you have this:

```
void func(set *a){
    func(a);
}
```

That is a non-terminating recursion, and hence stack overflow.

FWIW, you are clearly compiling the code as C++ since you use `reinterpret_cast<set>` which is only valid in C++.

Comment: Er, well, yes indeed. I restored the original code, because after your edit, well, there is no question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan +1 I have to ask. [The original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21518891/3) that included the VS2010 subsection did *not* have the code as you describe it here until you edited it in the 4th revision. Was it solely the "Stack Overflow" error that hinted you to the proposed problem and thus solution?

Comment: @WhozCraig Revision history is odd. I think it merged some revisions. When I wrote the answer the code was as per my answer. I copied the code in my answer using clipboard. Then asker edited the code to remove stack overflow. And I put it back.

Answer (score 0):

well the function prototype should be func1(Set **a)

Comment: @user3225284 *what* "worked"? Are you saying this doesn't *compile* undern VS ? Are you compiling the file as C rather than C++ ?

Comment: there is no C in vs2010 , i do c++ console application and include the **stdio.h** and **stdlib.h**

Comment: @user3225284 [There is no C in VS2010 ? ORLY ?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838(v=vs.100).aspx). If you're compiling C++ the `malloc` is invalid, and must be cast. And the same would be true if you were compiling C++ using g++ under CodeBlocks as well. Use the right compiler configuration and it will work under VS.